# How to convert sandbox google wallet account to production

Tags: android, android-pay

I am india developer. I have created merchant account into google.
I am using [following link](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial) to get steps to create account/

I have created sandbox account successfully and google also cut Rs. 50 from my account. Now, I want to convert this account to "production".

I click on [following link](https://www.google.com/errors/purchases/serviceUnavailable.html) suggested into No. 7 point.

But it say "Google wallet temporary not available".

Please suggest.